# How to get up-to-date cookies on every request? SocketIO

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

I want to get up-to-date cookies on every request from SocketIO client side

`socket.handshake.headers.cookie` and `socket.request.headers.cookie` have cookies that were received at the time the socket was connected

I also cannot use `document.cookie` for simple data insertion, since in this case cookies with the httpOnly flag that I need are not taken

What other ways are there?

Answer (score 0):

(updated) token based authentication is way to go but If you still want to get up-to-date cookie I would suggest the following methods:
Middlewares example:

Client-side:

```
// Assume you have a Socket.IO client set up
const socket = io();

then
    // Emit a "request" event along with the cookies
      socket.emit("request", { requestData, cookies });
```

Server-side:

```
// Event handler for the "request" event
  socket.on("request", (data) => {
    const { requestData, cookies } = data;
    console.log("Received request data:", requestData);
    console.log("Received cookies:", cookies);

  });
```

Let me know if this works for you or not

Comment: -extraHeaders? They are transmitted only at the time of connection, just like cookies. This option doesn't change anything at all.

-Use a Middleware for Cookie Handling? What middleware for example? socketio does not send new cookies, only the ones that were present at the time of connection. How will this option help then?